# "To sit in a Parliament" or "To sit on a Parliament"?

Tags: meaning

The phrasal verb "sit on sth" means "to be a member of a group of people". Well, according to [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sit), "to sit in / on sth" means "to be a member of a committee, parliament, or other official group", the same thing. I don't know why my phrasal verbs book "says" just "sit on sth" and doesn't say the "in" too. Perhaps Parliament can only be used with "in" with this meaning, I don't know. When I found the meaning of "sit on sth" for the first time, I realised that I could say "To sit on a Parliament" and not "To sit in a Parliament". Is my phrasal vebs book incomplete? Can "sit on a Parliament" be correct? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Please do not invoke the Sith Lords in our company. They are a terrible bother.

Comment: Grammar is no help here. Usage suggests (strongly supports) *in*, not *on*. Go ahead and use either in a generic sense; only *in* with reference to specific house.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of “sit in a Parliament” and  “sit on a Parliament” are correct.  Both are wrong. (*See added note.*)  The proper phrase is “sit in Parliament”.  Eg, see [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sit+in+a+Parliament%2Csit+on+a+Parliament%2Csit+in+Parliament&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *sit in a Parliament,sit on a Parliament,sit in Parliament*.

(*Added note:* More precisely, both are usually inappropriate as a way of saying that someone is a [Member of Parliament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_of_Parliament).  They are not grammar mistakes.  While some examples of use of  “sit in a Parliament” and  “sit on a Parliament”  may be found – as noted in FumbleFingers' answer – neither phrase is a customary English-language way to say that a person is a Member of Parliament.)

Phrase “sit on a jury” is common.  In common parlance it means to participate as a member of a jury, but – to digress – in Tenniel's illustration for *[Alice in Wonderland](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rgs/alice-XII.html)*, Alice appeared to sit on a jury without being a member of it:

[image: Tenniel in BW and colorized]

(Actually, it was merely that “she jumped up in such a hurry that she tipped over the jury-box with the edge of her skirt, upsetting all the jurymen on to the heads of the crowd below”, rather than sitting on the jury.)

Comment: Sit on a Parliament is funnier, though.

Comment: Shades (or perhaps I should say 'hues') of Ted Turner.

Comment: -1 for "Both are wrong." cf FumbleFingers.

Comment: @Kris, I added a note.

Comment: Nice picture. What's it about, though? And no link, no credits, no caption... :)

Comment: @Kris, I've added a picture explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Those Anglophones who *have* a Parliament (mine being the [mother of all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_mother_of_parliaments_%28expression%29), loosely speaking) don't usually refer to it using an article. Their elected representatives just [sit in Parliament](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sit%20in%20Parliament%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as jwpat says.

But on those rare occasions when we're talking about ***a*** parliament (*not* usually capitalised), the most common form is [sit **in** a parliament](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sit%20in%20a%20parliament%20then%20called%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (that's an old one - [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sit%20in%20a%20Parliament%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are many more recent usages).

Not that this means *sit **on** a parliament* is "incorrect" in any meaningful sense. There are no grammatical rules involved. It's just established custom and practice.

Comment: I hadn’t realized you were Icelandic.

Comment: I think it's fine that someone sat on the Parliament, just as Rand Paul sat on the US Senate for 13 hours the other day. By fine, I meant grammatically, rather than politically.

Comment: Nope, "sitting on the Parliament" just sounds wrong. In Canada at least we have "the Senate" and just plain "Parliament." The two words "the Parliament" would be followed by another word - in our case, invariably "buildings."

Comment: @James: As I said, **in** is the normal form - with or without an article. But I can see no feasible grammatical distinction between *parliament* and, say, *council, committee, meeting*, etc. So far as I'm concerned, that means using **on** is just *not what we usually do* - it's not "incorrect" grammatically speaking.